# Leave Ubuntu server to compute in background

Tags: ssh

I have access to a server running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I connect to it using XManager or PuTTY. But as soon as I close my client, I will be logged from the server. So is there a way how I could shut down my local machine and let the server compute for me.

I normally use the server for builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install screen
screen
```

You will now have a new console prompt.  Anything you do in here will continue to run after your SSH session closes.  When you reconnect with SSH later:

`screen -dr`

You are now reconnected to your screen session, which continued running while you were gone.

If you create more than one screen session, you'll get a list of all the screen sessions currently running when you do `screen -dr` as above - just do `screen -dr pid` (where *pid* is the pid number of the session you want to reconnect to) in order to choose one.

Typing `exit` while in a screen session will close the screen session for good, just as it would in a normal SSH or other console session.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a process in the background by using an Ampersand (&). For example

`sh example.sh &`

would run the script `example.sh` in the background. You can then safely logoff and return later to check if the script has finished.

Comment: I have to give that in the shell right? Even my shell exits when I close my `PuTTY`

Comment: Yes you have to input that into the shell.
Your shell needs to exit as soon as you close your client, because by exiting the client you're closing the connection to the server.

Comment: @fotomonster this wont work. The prozess still would be bound on the specific shell and dies when this is closed. What you seem to search is "screen"
http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html Also "nohup" would fit.

Comment: Nohup does work - but you need to do `nohup *command* &`, complete with trailing ampersand, for it to work.  Also: screen is almost always a better solution for this kind of thing.  Details for usage in an answer below, in case the manpage is a bit too chewy to get you started (I avoided screen for far too long for exactly that reason; I wish somebody had explained it to me simply!)